# shrinkwrap complex thing

Tags: particles

I'm trying to shrinkwrap a field of objects distributed onto a topographical mesh, so as to make a closed mesh for printing. I have many objects distributed over a guide mesh using the particle system. It looks like what I want, but I'd like some pointers on how to most quickly approximate this array of things with one draped and/or shrinkwrapped mesh.

[image]

Comment: Can you add images that show what you have so far?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I added an image. I'm new to this forum. There's probably a smoother way to add stuff ... I really want just the stuff on the top - the grey mesh running through all the objects can serve as the base plane. With a simpler test I draped a cloth mesh over it, then shrinkwrapped it, and that was nice, but now it's a bit complex ...